# GETJson pass two parameters to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why in this code I only pass "term" to server

```
$.getJSON( "{{route('search.index')}}", {
                term: request.term,
                type: $('#category_input').attr('data-type')
        }, response );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON( "{{route('search.index')}}", {
                term: request.term,
                type: $('#category_input').data('type')
        }, response );
```

Try the cod above. It should be because you didn’t access it with the data function